# How to get the gross total and net total of an order in magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Do i have to calculate gross total and net total or are they stored in the database. can some one give me a help. If they are stored in the db what are the tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Load the order by

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

if you have order increment id then load the order by

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

and then retrieve the grand total by

```
$grandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
```

Answer (score 0):

getGrandTotal returns the gross total. AFAIK you have to calculate the net total, but it should be easy enough:

```
$gross = $order->getGrandTotal();
$tax = $order->getTaxAmount();
$net = $gross - $tax;
```